# Running ros2 node inside blender venv

Tags: ros, blender, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to run simple ros2 node inside blender environment.

The node should render some scenario and publish the frames to a topic using cv_bridge.

I tried to source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash and build a workspace
in the scripts folder before running blender. After that,  execute the node's script from blender, but It can't find the ros2 python packages and fails to run simple publisher node.

Any ideas of how I can get it to work?

Thanks in advance,
Iftach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390526/running-ros2-node-inside-blender-venv/) by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
ROS 2 is Python 3 only. You've tagged this `python2.7`, so that would appear not to work.

**Comment by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) on 2021-11-10**:
Wrong tagget, my bad.
The blender environment's python version is 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I manage to make this work, it's not pretty and I'm sure that this is a correct solution but:

copy the desired ros2 packages (rclpy, std_msgs etc..) to /path/to/blender/scripts/modules (i copied the whole ros2 package folder)

--- if your ros2 python env doesnt match the python version of blender ---

- in each package edit the name of the .so file, for example, I work with python 3.8.10 and blender was with python 3.9.2 (2.93.5 version of blender) so the file: **std_msgs_s__rosidl_typesupport_c.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** inside std_msgs package was changed to **std_msgs_s__rosidl_typesupport_c.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so**.
  probably you will have to debug it for few tries until you change everything in all the packages

---

Originally posted by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) with karma: 23 on 2021-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0